# Need help in adding a JProgressBar to a swing application

Tags: java, swing, file-upload, jprogressbar

I am using the following code to upload a file to server using a PUT request. This works properly. But I want to add a `JProgressBar` to this this code, how do you suggest I do that? I am not sure of which classes to use to achieve the progressbar I need.

```
RequestEntity re = new RequestEntity() {
    @Override
    public long getContentLength() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return file.length();
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRepeatable() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeRequest(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            int l;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((l = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, l);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You haven't shown any GUI code whatsoever, do you have any?  Or do you expect others to write it?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185924/show-progress-during-ftp-file-upload-in-a-java-applet/12186144#12186144) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272842/multithreading-in-java-i-want-both-ui-and-code-to-execute-in-parallel/16272933#16272933) for examples

Comment: I am sory roippi about that, but there is too much of code put, thats the reason I did not put it up.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Tip:  Add @roippi (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.

Comment: oh hi I just got notified of a new comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a byte is read, add one to a counter. Provide a method to return the number of bytes total and the number of bytes read. In the GUI code, set the maximum value of the progress bar to the number of bytes, and start a timer that periodically calls `progress.setValue` with the current number of bytes read.

Comment: Then make sure the the uploads occurs in its own thread, and your UI updates are taking place in the EDT - or just use a SwingWorker instead

Comment: Yup, I used this solution and it works properly, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just put a [`javax.swing.ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) into the input stack.